# Parameterless overloaded constructor calling parametrized one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hello and sorry for the confusing title, I can't express properly what I want to say. 
On to the question, how should I interpret this snippet?

```
public class Node
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    /// Creates a Node which has the supplied id.
    public Node(long id) : this()
    {
        Id = id;
    }
/* */ 
}
```

If I am not wrong; when a Node is created with the parametrized constructor, the `this` keyword should call the same method, but without parameter, which I suppose should default to the default(sic), empty constructor. At the end it looks like this is just another way of calling the empty, default constructor, which would be pointless.
And if instead the constructor work as intended, how can the `Id` member be instantiated?

Complete sourcecode is here: http://sourceforge.net/p/satsumagraph/code/ci/master/tree/src/Graph.cs#l38

Comment: Your current code doesn't have default constructor *(parameter less)* and you should get an error: 'Node' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: That code isn't the actual code - can you show the real, actual code?

Comment: Note that the actual code, within the Graph.cs class, shows that Node is a struct, not a class: http://sourceforge.net/p/satsumagraph/code/ci/master/tree/src/Graph.cs

Comment: not a good idea but if you want to initialize then use default arguments in the parametrized construtor. long id = 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your actual code, `Node` is a `struct`, not a class.

Adding the call to the default constructor is required in that case.  Without it, you get a message saying the object "cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to" since you're using an automatic property in a value type.  This is because the compiler adds a backing field, and that field must be initialized before you can access the property.  The constructor is trying to set the property before the field would be initialized.  Every `struct` includes a default constructor, and calling it "zero-initializes" the backing field for the automatic property, allowing it to function correctly.

With a `class`, as you demonstrated, this would be unnecessary (and not even compile).

Comment: Perfect, that was my reading fault after all. Thanks for the explaining!

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx):-

> A constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by using the this keyword. Like base, this can be used with or without parameters, and any parameters in the constructor are available as parameters to this, or as part of an expression.

When you compile the above code, it should give you an error, because you haven't defined a parameterless constructor .

Therefore, when you do this:-

```
  public Node(long id) : this()
  {
      Id = id;
  }
```

You are trying to call the parameterless constructor, which you haven't defined.